# I'm not able to store a 2nd received variable into my function

Tags: javascript, string, function

I have a function, that receive 2 values, both of them like:

```
MyFunction("word1","word2")
```

And then my function receives them:

```
MyFunction(test1,test2){}
```

Thing is, that for the first value, I have no problem to store it, but 2nd value, I'm not able to.

I've tried something like:

```
var String=test2.toString(); // Doesn't work
var String=String(test2); // Doesn't work
```

and many other ways and no luck...

What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "store"? Please add a [mcve]. Show what you've tried.

Comment: No need to do anything. Its already a string. In case you pass any numbers you may do `var string = test2+""`. So if `test2=10` then string will contain `"10"`

Comment: `MyFunction("word1","word2"); function MyFunction(test1,test2){console.log(test1);console.log(test2);}` run in console log, will log exactly as `word1 word2`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question as-asked doesn't really make any sense, and the one answer that attempts to answer it has been ignored. OP has instead posted an answer that seems to be a completely different question, and is perhaps the actual question that he was trying to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get the way you present the question, but I'll give it a shot. Assuming that you have a function as follows:

```
function MyFunction(test1, test2){
  //doSomething...
}
```

and you call it like this:

```
MyFunction("string1", "string2");
```

Then you should be able to call the values of string1 and string2 by using the variables test1 and test2 in the function. This is because a variable (var) in JS is basically a all-in-one variable (this will make sense if you have programmed in languages like java, c, c++, etc.). Therefore, the variable test1 can be an integer, string, character, floating-point value and more. If you call the function with test1 and test2 as strings, you can use them as strings, and the same holds for any other data type.

If you want to troubleshoot or debug a piece of code, you can always use the alert function in javascript:

```
alert("Variable x has value " + x);
```

You could use this to see if anything is wrong with your variables both inside MyFunction(), and inside the function where MyFunction() is called (to check for any differences or mistakes).

Let me know if it helped!

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
fun = function(str1, str2) {
    let name = str1;
    let age = str2
    console.log("Hi my name %s", name);
    console.log("And my age is %s", age); 
}


fun("Amit Sinha", "30");
```

Comment: Why not name the parameters `name` and `age`?

Comment: Yes, you may name the parameter name and age. I have added that 2 line for extra knowledge about local and global variable nothing else. You may continue with str1 and str2 as well.